# Magento 2 add custom field in checkout place order

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs, validation, place-order

Need to add new custom validation on the checkout page before place order.

[image]

The place order should work only when the calculation shown above is correct and also to show different values to sum.

I have override Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/templates/payment.html to show this field but I couldn't add the validations

Comment: Do you need to catch the customer click and place order event to test your custom field? You have to handle it with js currently you are just rendering and not processing requests so it won't work.

Comment: Yes I have to do the exactly same